# How to Restrict access to Sharepoint Online sites only for user using App in AAD

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, azure-devops, sharepoint-online

I am relatively new in Sharepoint and Azure, i got a task to recreate a case of logging to sharepoint online site using powershell with m365 cli and TenantID and AppID environmentals, so i need to log in using something like this:

`$env:CLIMICROSOFT365_AADAPPID="someidkey"`

`$env:CLIMICROSOFT365_TENANT="sometenantidkey"`

`m365 login --authType password --userName "testuser@domain.onmicrosoft.com" --password "somepassword"`

I know it works on ot her apps

As for now i created Application in Azure Active Directory

in authentication i added mobile and deskotp application and checked https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient

i allowed public client flows

in api permission i putted Sharepoint Delegated AllSites.Write
I Used Assignment required for application
and i assigned application to "testuser"

Lets call this app: "Update Sharepoint"

Then i went to my sharepoint online site, used `/_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx` to grant permission
putted in App ID: ID for "Update Sharepoit"
in App Domain: domain.onmicrosoft.com
in Redirect url: http://domain.onmicrosoft.com
and in xml request

`<AppPermissionRequests><AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" /></AppPermissionRequests>`

My user is native user so he has disabled mfa, and is in member group of sharepoint site

However i can still just log in using just login and password and update the sharepoint site, using powershell.

What am i missing? How can i restrict sharepoint site that it needs to accept TenantID and AppID